# How to get only new data inserted from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making a small application. trying to retrieve posts inserted, and then I want to retrieve only new inserted posts, and not retrieving all the posts again.

So do you have any idea on how to I can retrieve last items ( Since the list object retrieved)

Here my Query code :

```
public void getFeed(int limit, int skip){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Feed");
        query.setSkip(skip);
        query.setLimit(limit);

        query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> feedList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < feedList.size(); i++) {
                        Post p = new Post(feedList.get(i).get("Text").toString());
                        mAdapter.addItem(p);


                    }
                    Log.d("result", "Here is it:" + feedList.size());

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                } else {
                    Log.d("Feed", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

keep the last time you checked and then use that time to pull anything greater than the last time checked from the `createdAt` column or `updatedAt` column (if its possible for someone to update something you are pulling) of the object. then after your query is finished update that time to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the viewed posts count and next time when retrieving the list set the count as parameter for skip:

```
query.setSkip(count);
```

Comment: I don't wanna retrieve the older posts, but the newest

Comment: on what basis you want categorise older and newer posts, whether time or view by a user. Because a same old post for one user can be a new post for other user.

Comment: I wanna retrieve new posts

Comment: i get you but on what basis you want to categorise new posts??

Comment: Well since the last object retrieved I guess it possible to retrieve posts after that object

Comment: that is what i am trying to tell.